# Chaining multiple firebase actions and rollbacks

Tags: javascript, firebase, chaining

I'm using firebase and I want to chain some actions. Here is the scenario:
I want to add an item to the array and because I don't want to use push Id's I update a 'Last_Id' variable in firebase every time an item is added. I also update a 'Counter' variable to count the number of records (so I don't end up using numChildren() which can be slow).
The count and last_id variable are in the same tree like this:
Count:
---------->last_id
---------->Counter
I did this so that they can both be updated at the same time in a single transaction

So when I add an item I want 3 things to happen in order:

1. 1- last_id is retreived
2. Item is added
3. last_id and Counter are
   both updated

This is my code which makes use of promises.

```
add:function(ref,obj){

     //get last_id
    return baseRef.child('Count').child("Last_Id").once("value")
            .then(function(snapshot){
              return (snapshot.val()+1);
            })
    //add new data
          .then(function(key){
               return baseRef.child(ref).child(key).set(obj,function(error){ 
                    if (error)
                       console.log(error.code)
                    })    
           })
   //update Count and last key
           .then(this.updateCountAndKey(ref,1))


},


updateCountAndKey:function(ref,i){
   return baseRef.child('Count').transaction(function(currentValue) {
      if (currentValue!==null)
            return {
                 Counter:(currentValue.Counter||0) +i,
                 Last_Id:(currentValue.Last_Id||0)+1
                 }
    },function(err,commited,snap) {
        if( commited ) 
           console.log("updated counter to "+ snap.val());
        else {
            console.log("oh no"+err);
        }
    },false)

}
```

since I'm new to javascript and promises in particular want to know if this is a robust way of doing things. I also want to know how to do roll-backs if something goes wrong. so that if one thing fails then everything else fails (e.g if the update to Last_id and Counter fail then the item is not added).
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

As the Firebase [documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/transaction.html) specifies , transactions can only `Atomically modify the data at this location`, hence you  can't use transactions to update other nodes in Firebase.

It is recommended to use push ID's (generated by Firebase in a safe way). This will remove the need to use a transaction for this part of your process. You will need to still use a transaction if you need to maintain the count. This should be done on success of #2 (adding an item).

Now your process will look like this:

1. push an item (auto generated ID)
2. on success, use a transaction to increment the count

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am aware of this, which is why I put the last_id and Counter in the same location . I wanted them  both to be updated at the same time. What about rollbacks do you have any advice for that??